# javascript check if date object is at least 5 minutes old (nodeJS)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

How to compare a date object in javascript to check if the object is at least 5 minutes old? I tried:

```
//current date
var date = new Date();
//data from database
console.log("db: " + data_from_database)
console.log("current date: " + date)

//how to check if "data_from_database is at least 5 minutes old?
```

> db: Sun Jul 16 2017 23:59:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)
>
> current date: Sun Jul 16 2017
>   14:12:43 GMT+0200 (CEST)

How to perform the check the simplest way without creating tons of new objects?

Answer (score 23):

You would get the time in milliseconds when you `subtract` two dates and then you can `compare`

```
var date = new Date();
//data from database
console.log("db: " + data_from_database)
console.log("current date: " + date)

var FIVE_MIN=5*60*1000;

if((date - new Date(date_from_database)) > FIVE_MIN) {
   console.log('Delayed by more than 5 mins');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date(data_from_database);
if(date1-date2 > 5*60*1000){
   do something
}
```